# PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two **independent** models : `User` and `Invitation`. I'm trying to check a condition in these 2 different table with ActiveRecord.

**Schema.rb**

```
create_table "invitations", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "invit_name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer "sign_in_count", default: 0, null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.inet "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.inet "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "provider"
    t.string "uid"
    t.string "facebook_picture_url"
    t.string "first_name"
    t.string "last_name"
    t.boolean "admin"
    t.string "invit_ref"
    t.string "invit_one"
    t.string "invit_two"
    t.string "token"
    t.datetime "token_expiry"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end
```

**Problem:**

```
User.where(:invit_one =>invit_ref)
 .or(User.where(:invit_two=>invit_ref))
 .or(Invitation.where(:invit_name =>invit_ref)).blank?
```

I can either do `Invitation.where(:invit_name =>invit_ref).blank?` alone or `User.where(:invit_two =>invit_ref).blank?` but not combine the two expressions

Unfortunately, I get a `"PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "invitations"` on this simple query.

Can you help me to figure why?

Comment: does the dup question helped you?

Comment: Unfortunately not really. I saw this answer before posting but in my scenario, I have no join table!

Comment: My two table are completely independents

Comment: add the schame.rb for those 2 tables

Comment: Done! Thanks Arup

Comment: You can't link different tables with the active record `or` method, see https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-or and note where it says "The two relations must be... scoping the same model"

Comment: Yes this is correct reason.

Comment: Thanks. Is there an alternative?

Comment: @Bonapara What are you trying to do?